# Is it possible to replace an item in the JSON array with the help of a pointer using Vert.x JSON Pointer?

Tags: java, json, vert.x, jsonpointer

While using Vert.x, for manipulating JSONs I'm using a JSON Pointer. Recently came across having to do the same with JSON arrays.

Here's the sample code I tried.

```java
String jsonInput = "{\"string\":\"string\",\"json\":{\"items\":[\"item-1\",\"item-2\",\"item-3\"]}}";
JsonObject json = new JsonObject(jsonInput);
JsonPointer pointer = JsonPointer.from("/json/items/0");
System.out.println(pointer.writeJson(json,"new item"));
```

Consider this as the input

```json
{
    "string": "string",
    "json": {
        "items": [
            "item-1",
            "item-2",
            "item-3"
        ]
    }
}
```

The pointer to `item-1` would be `/json/items/0`. When I use the same with JsonPointer from Vert.x instead of replacing the existing item, it ends up adding another element instead of writing at index zero like below

```json
{
    "string": "string",
    "json": {
        "items": [
            "<newly-written-item>"
            "item-1",
            "item-2",
            "item-3"
        ]
    }
}
```

Is it possible to overwrite the existing value instead of adding at the index ?

Answer (score 0):

I think it is not possible with `writeJson()` as it always adds the new element at the given index. In the implementation from vertx's [repository](https://github.com/eclipse-vertx/vert.x/blob/5066fa4f55d8466b9519fa069e98a2780334022a/src/main/java/io/vertx/core/json/pointer/impl/JsonPointerIteratorImpl.java#L21) you can see that vertx always uses the following method to write array elements, which can only add a new element:

```
public boolean writeArrayElement(Object value, int i, Object el) {
    if (isArray(value)) {
      try {
        ((JsonArray)value).getList().add(i, el);
        return true;
      } catch (IndexOutOfBoundsException e) {
        return false;
      }
    } else return false;
  }
```

For JsonObjects, vertx uses the following method, which will replace existing values:

```
  @Override
  public boolean writeObjectParameter(Object value, String key, Object el) {
    if (isObject(value)) {
      ((JsonObject)value).put(key, el);
      return true;
    } else return false;
  }
```

A possible workaround could be to query the `JsonArray` and manually replace the array element like this:

```
String jsonInput = "{\"string\":\"string\",\"json\":{\"items\":[\"items-1\",\"item-2\",\"item-3\"]}}";
JsonObject json = new JsonObject(jsonInput);
JsonPointer pointer = JsonPointer.from("/json/items");
JsonArray jsonArray = (JsonArray) pointer.queryJson(json);
jsonArray.remove(0);
jsonArray.add(0, "new item");

System.out.println(json);
```

Output:

```
{"string":"string","json":{"items":["new item","item-2","item-3"]}}
```

Comment: The context here is this path and data both are external to the system that I'm building, so I wouldn't always know if a part of pointer is referring to a JSON Array.